# R - sum of several non-overlapping time series (forecasts)

Tags: r, sum, time-series

I have 24 time series forecasts that I want the cumulative sum of. Here are just two, as they produce the error I'm encountering:

```
forecast(arima(P1, c(0,0,0)), h = 6)$mean
      Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov      Dec    
2012                                                                     12.81818                                                     
2013 12.81818 12.81818 12.81818 12.81818 12.81818
```

Going from december 2012 to May 2013.

```
forecast(arima(P2, c(0,0,0)), h = 6)$mean
      Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun
2014 12.94118 12.94118 12.94118 12.94118 12.94118 12.94118
```

Going from January 2014 to June 2014.

I have tried to add them using a dummy timeseries with all 0's to hold intermediate results, but when I add the first to the dummy timeseries, it gets cut off at the end of it (for P1, that is May 2013), and then trying to add the second just returns an error message that the time series are not intersecting.

Is there some way of doing this? I would like a time series like this to be my result:

```
          Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug          Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec
2011  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000      0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
2012  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000      0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 12.94118
2013 12.81818 12.81818 12.81818 12.81818 12.81818  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000      0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
2014 12.94118 12.94118 12.94118 12.94118 12.94118 12.94118
```

Some of the timeseries to add have overlaps, some don't.

I know that R has the hts package for hierarchical time series forecasts, but I need the forecasts to be done with the arima(0,0,0) model for illustrative purposes...

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's the answer. There may be a better way of doing it, but this works:

```
#create dummy time series ts0
ts0 <- ts(rep(0,42), start = c(2011, 1), frequency = 12)

#merge alle forecasts with ts0 using ts.union
ts.union(ts0, forecast(arima(P1, c(0,0,0)), h = 6)$mean, forecast(arima(P2, c(0,0,0)), h = 6)$mean, ..., forecast(arima(P24, c(0,0,0)), h = 6)$mean)

#get row sums using rowSums
ts0sums <- rowSums(ts0)

#make into time series again
ts1 <- ts(ts0sums, start = c(2011, 1), frequency = 12)

#change 0's to NAs for plotting with "holes"
ts1[ts1 == 0] <- NA

#ts1
            Jan        Feb        Mar        Apr        May        Jun            Jul        Aug        Sep        Oct        Nov        Dec
2011         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA             NA         NA         NA         NA         NA   9.000000
2012   9.000000   9.000000   9.000000   9.000000   9.000000         NA             NA         NA  13.428571  13.428571  13.428571  76.774109
2013  78.631252  78.631252  65.202681  65.202681  65.202681   1.857143             NA         NA         NA         NA         NA  18.411765
2014 430.440131 430.440131 430.440131 430.440131 430.440131 412.028367
```